# Extract first and last words from strings as a new column in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to create two new columns based on string in another column.

what I have

```
     Profile
0    Technician
1    Service Engineer
2    Sales and Service Support Engineer
```

what I like to have

```
     First              Last
0    Technician         NaN
1    Service            Engineer
2    Sales              Engineer
```

My attempt was to use solutions like

```
new = tl['Profile'].str.split(' ')
tl['First'] = new[0]
tl['Last'] = new[1]
```

But this is correct only for First.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `str.extract` here:

```
df['Profile'].str.extract(r'^(?P<First>\S+).*?(?P<Last>\S+)?$')

        First      Last
0  Technician       NaN
1     Service  Engineer
2       Sales  Engineer
```

Not many `str` methods will be as elegant as this because of the additional need to handle sentences with one word only.

---

You can also use `str.partition` here.

```
u = df['Profile'].str.partition()
pd.DataFrame({'First': u[0], 'Last': u[2].str.split().str[-1]})

        First      Last
0  Technician       NaN
1     Service  Engineer
2       Sales  Engineer
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex, using loops

For last name

```py
k=[]
for i in df_names_test['Name']:
    h=len(i.split(" "))
    j=i.split(" ")[h-1]
    k.append(j)


df_names_test["Last"]=k
```

for first name

```py
k=[]
for i in df_names_test['Name']:

    j=i.split(" ")[0]
    k.append(j)


df_names_test["First"]=k
```

Using Lambda functions:
First name

```py
df_names_test['First']=df_names_test['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0])
```

Last name:

```py
df_names_test['Last']=df_names_test['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1])
```